# How to compare with other json objects's value

Tags: python, json

I have a list :

`a_list` :

```
[{'score': 60, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'A01', 'subject': 'math'}, 
{'score': 70, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'A01', 'subject': 'music'}, 
{'score': 65, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'B01', 'subject': 'science'}, 
{'score': 35, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'C02', 'subject': 'math'}]
```

And I query(django) from db get a list ,each `subject` has its own `pass_mark`

```
pass_list =  ClassData.objects.values('subject','pass_mark')
```

`pass_list`:

```
[{'pass_mark': 50, 'subject_all': u'math'}, 
{'pass_mark':70, 'subject_all': u'science'}, 
{'pass_mark': 70, 'subject_all': u'music'}]
```

And I have to compare `a_list` to check the `pass_mark` is higher than `pass_list`

So the result list would be:

```
[{'score': 60, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'A01', 'subject': 'math'}, 
{'score': 70, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'A01', 'subject': 'music'}]
```

Here is my method :

```
result_list = []
for a in a_list:
    check = [x for x in pass_list if x['subject_all'] == a['subject']]
    if a['score'] >= check[0]['pass_mark']:
        result_list.append(a)
print result_list
```

I want to know is there more faster or better method
Because the `a_list`  will be a large one in the future

Comment: Not sure what you mean by faster since it looks like you'll need to do a linear scan over `a_list` and `pass_list` for each of those values anyways

Comment: @cricket_007, not if you create a mapping from subject to score with a dict, then you have a linear solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dict where the `keys` are subjects and the values are `scores`:

```
l = [{'score': 60, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'A01', 'subject': 'math'},
     {'score': 70, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'A01', 'subject': 'music'},
     {'score': 65, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'B01', 'subject': 'science'},
     {'score': 35, 'credit': 5, 'class': 'C02', 'subject': 'math'}]

l2 = [{'pass_mark': 50, 'subject_all': u'math'},
      {'pass_mark': 70, 'subject_all': u'science'},
      {'pass_mark': 70, 'subject_all': u'music'}]

sub = {dct["subject_all"]: dct["pass_mark"] for dct in l2}

result = [dct for dct in l if dct["score"] >= sub[dct["subject"]]]

print(result)
```

output:

```
[{'credit': 5, 'score': 60, 'class': 'A01', 'subject': 'math'}, {'credit': 5, 'score': 70, 'class': 'A01', 'subject': 'music'}]
```

You just do one pass over `l2` to build the dict, and one pass over `l` with constant work elsewhere so  the solution is `O(n)`  as opposed to your own quadratic approach.  Ideally if you could create the `sub` dict in the first place it would be the best approach.